# Grouping of nodes into equal sized nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I've an document where the data in each node is different and there is one node which has the attribute as end Tag. I am trying to create pages of data with equal lines in all the pages and if one of the nodes data cannot be on the page then all of the node data should be moved to the next page. Also there is the node with the "End Tag" which should be in the last page.

Example Input:

```
<Book>
<node>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
</node>
<node>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
</node>
<node>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
</node>
<node>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
</node>
<node>
    <line>First 2</line>
    <line>Second 2</line>
    <line>Third 2</line>
    <line>Fourth 2</line>
</node>
<node endTag="Y">
    <line>End</line>
    <line>Data</line>
    <line/>
</node>
```

Desired Output is page with 5 lines of data:

```
<Book>
<Page>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
</Page>
<Page>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
    <line>Test</line>
    <line/>
    <line/>
</Page>
<Page>
    <line>First 2</line>
    <line>Second 2</line>
    <line>Third 2</line>
    <line>Fourth 2</line>
    <line/>
</Page>
<Page>
    <line/>
    <line/>
    <line>End</line>
    <line>Data</line>
    <line/>
</Page>
```

Comment: Show your XSLT-code.

Comment: @Jeroen Heier :  I had the code like `<xsl:for-each-group select="/Book/node/line" 
         group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
  <Page>
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </Page>
</xsl:for-each-group>`. The problem is that i do not want it just group by 5 elements. It should also take into consideration if the whole tag <node> can be in the <Page> else it has to move to the next page. And also the end tag should always be in the last page.

Comment: Unfortunate choice of element name: I was confused between "nodes" and "elements named 'node'".

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/Book/line" 
         group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
  <Page>
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </Page>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: @Michale Kay: Thanks for your reply. The problem with this is it does not put the whole node into the same page element. So if the whole node does not fit in the page then i need to move it to the next page and then add the empty lines for the previous page.